# Как прервать цикл из другого объекта?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

Вот есть у меня цикл:

```
for (domain in databaseResponseLiveData.value!!) {
        DomainsAPI.retrofitDomainService.getDomainDescriptionWithRetrofit())
            .enqueue(object : Callback<String> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<String>, t: Throwable) {
                currentDomainLiveData.value = "ERROR"

                Timber.e("failure on ${databaseResponseLiveData.value!!.indexOf(domain)} element")
                Timber.e(t)
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<String>, response: Response<String>) {
                downloadingResult[domain] = response.body()!!
                currentDomainLiveData.value = domain
            }
        })
    }
```

Я хочу его прервать в случае вызова функции onFailure(). То есть если ошибка, мне надо выполнить сразу код после цикла и больше ничего не загружать. Как такое можно реализовать?

Comment: на момент выполнения onFailure или onResponse ваш цикл уже давно отработает, потому что enqueue - асинхронная операция

Comment: Ладно, тогда по другому вопрос задам. Как прекратить выполнение таких же объектов? То есть у меня несколько тысяч раз выполняется эта операция. Например, если на 571 разе `onFailure`, то прекратить выполнять остальные объекты, то есть 572 раз и так далее должны быть не отработаны

Comment: @IR42, то есть получается, что мне надо отменить всю очередь из нескольких тысяч объектов, в случае ошибки одного. Можно ли это как-то сделать?

Comment: у вас подразумевается последовательное обращение к сервису или параллельное? в текущей реализации у вас параллельно идут запросы. И какие нужно отменить? Все или те, что идут после ошибочного?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хоть это и не совсем правильно, но не зная всей архитектуры приложения можно подсказать попробовать выкрутиться так:

```
val requests = mutableListOf<Call>()
for (domain in databaseResponseLiveData.value!!) {
    val request = DomainsAPI.retrofitDomainService.getDomainDescriptionWithRetrofit())
    request.enqueue(object : Callback<String> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<String>, t: Throwable) {
                currentDomainLiveData.value = "ERROR"

                requests.forEach { it.cancel() } 

                Timber.e("failure on ${databaseResponseLiveData.value!!.indexOf(domain)} element")
                Timber.e(t)
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<String>, response: Response<String>) {
                downloadingResult[domain] = response.body()!!
                currentDomainLiveData.value = domain
            }
        })
    requests.add(request)
}
```

Насколько я помню, `cancel()` можно вызывать сколько угодно раз и в любом состоянии запроса.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает